# I have this triangle in my Html/CSS Code and i dont know what is that

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this

```
  th.asc a:after {
    content: '▲';
}
```

What can type on keyboard that can make that symbol show up?
What is this symbol? When should I use it?

Comment: And where'd you get that code piece?

Comment: It's a geometric shape, part of the Unicode character set. It's called an upwards triangle.

Comment: This code is in the default Site.Css of Visual Studio...
I didnt know it was a Unicode Char thx for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That character will be rendered after the `<a>` tag which is inside the `th` tag and probably looking at your class name `asc` it indicates **ascending sorting**, it is just used as an icon to represent ascending sort

More on CSS [content](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) property

Info on [triangle character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b2/index.htm)

```
th.asc a:after
     ---^---
/* This makes the content character render after the <a> tag which is inside 
   th having class .asc which I assume stands for ascending, if you use :before 
   instead of :after, triangle will be rendered before the <a> tag text */
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a Unicode character, that besides giving support to all the different alphabets in the world, have graphics chars.

You have a lot of pages to look for unicode characters. One specially curious is

[shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/)

where you can draw the shape that you wanty.

Specifying them in the CSS is easy, you just have to put the number behind a backslash

'\25A0'

is a square